# How to use ffmpeg to concatenate subtitles only?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, subtitle

I have 4 subtitle segments each in 1 mkv container. Now I want to concatenate them to 1 stream so I can mux it with video and audio streams.

I tried

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:\
22082016-0749_sub_seg1.mkv|\           => 505 KB
22082016-0749_sub_seg2.mkv|\           => 401 KB
22082016-0749_sub_seg3.mkv|\           => 489 KB
22082016-0749_sub_seg4.mkv" \          => 243 KB
-c:s copy -y \
22082016-0749_sub_complete.mkv         => 505 KB, should be ~1638 KB
```

But this only copies the first segment.

I also tried

```
ffmpeg -canvas_size 492x250 -fix_sub_duration -txt_format bitmap -txt_page 149 -ss 00:14:12.000 -i 22082016-0749.mts -to 00:27:18.480 -map 0:s:0 -c:s dvd_subtitle -y 22082016-0749_sub_seg1.mkv
ffmpeg -canvas_size 492x250 -fix_sub_duration -txt_format bitmap -txt_page 149 -ss 00:48:57.800 -i 22082016-0749.mts -to 00:26:34.960 -map 0:s:0 -c:s dvd_subtitle -y 22082016-0749_sub_seg2.mkv
ffmpeg -canvas_size 492x250 -fix_sub_duration -txt_format bitmap -txt_page 149 -ss 01:23:14.840 -i 22082016-0749.mts -to 00:26:59.200 -map 0:s:0 -c:s dvd_subtitle -y 22082016-0749_sub_seg3.mkv
ffmpeg -canvas_size 492x250 -fix_sub_duration -txt_format bitmap -txt_page 149 -ss 01:58:03.120 -i 22082016-0749.mts -to 00:19:13.680 -map 0:s:0 -c:s dvd_subtitle -y 22082016-0749_sub_seg4.mkv
```

(The above command works, the command below does not)

```
ffmpeg \
-i 22082016-0749_sub_seg1.mkv \
-i 22082016-0749_sub_seg2.mkv \
-i 22082016-0749_sub_seg3.mkv \
-i 22082016-0749_sub_seg4.mkv \
-filter_complex "\
[0:s]trim=0:1638.480,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[g1];\
[1:s]trim=0:1594.960,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[g2];\
[2:s]trim=0:1619.200,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[g3];\
[3:s]trim=0:1140.680,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[g4];\
[g1][g2][g3][g4]concat=n=4[out]" \
-map [out] -c:s copy -y \
22082016-0749_sub_complete.mkv
```

This runs into the following error:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x17da5a0] timebase 1/1000000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (dvdsub) -> trim
  Stream #1:0 (dvdsub) -> trim
  Stream #2:0 (dvdsub) -> trim
  Stream #3:0 (dvdsub) -> trim
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

OR is there a way to directly do this all in one step from splitting it to segments and again merging them together?

It's important to keep the durations.

Comment: In your MTS -> MKV step, copy audio as well. Then in first command (concat), map and copy audio and subs. Then strip the audio out. Long story short, conventional subs don't carry timestamps and the concat demuxer relies on them for proper offseting and merging.

Comment: Good idea! I tried that but it also stops after the first segment:
size=   77689kB time=00:27:19.00 bitrate= 388.3kbits/s speed=51.6x
video:0kB audio:76830kB subtitle:487kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.480842%

Comment: Hold on. I missed you are using the concat protocol. Use the [demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1).